# Верстка карточек разного размера

Tags: html, css, sass

Стоит задача заверстать карточки. Все бы ничего, но оттого, что первая карточка больше остальных, не получается заверстать ее во флексе. Подскажите, каким образом верстать такие карточки на флексе?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если принципиально нужно через **flex**, то следует задавать пропорции параметром **flex-basis** (хотя для сравнения стоило бы попробовать и **grid**)

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.std-item {
  flex-basis: 33%;
}

.big-item {
  flex-basis: 66%;
}

.card {
  background-color: beige;
  margin: .5em;
  height: 5em;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="big-item">
      <div class="card">Item 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="std-item">
      <div class="card">Item 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="std-item">
      <div class="card">Item 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="std-item">
      <div class="card">Item 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="std-item">
      <div class="card">Item 5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!